# Point class. distance formula. logic issue when plugging coordinate from the constructor and getting wrong result

Tags: distance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
class point{ // define point class
private:
    float x=0;
    float y=0;

public:
    point();// default constructor
    point(float, float);// constructor
    void  setX(float);
    void   setY(float);
    double getX()const;
    double getY()const;    

};
//implement all the member function
point::point(){    }
point::point(float i, float k){
    x=i;
    y=k;
}
void point::setX(float xc){
    x=xc;
}

void point::setY(float yc){
    y=yc;
}

double point::getY()const{
    return y;
}

double point::getX()const{
    return x;
}

double operator + (const point&lhs, const point &rhs) // free function.
{
    double dx=lhs.getX()-rhs.getX();
    double dy=lhs.getX()-rhs.getY();
    return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}
int main(){
    point p1(2, -1);
    point p2(1, 5);
    int dist=0;
    dist = p1 + p2;
    cout << "The distance between p1 "  << "and p2" << " is " <<  dist << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This should be 5 but I got 3. I do not understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
double dy=lhs.getX()-rhs.getY();
```

by

```
double dy=lhs.getY()-rhs.getY()
```

Comment: Happy to help you! Please, can you accept the answer. Thanks.